# Angularjs ui utils highlight filter breaks application on search

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, angular-ui, angularjs-ui-utils

I am using Angular ui-utils  highlight filter and I have the following code:

```
<span data-ng-bind-html="organization.level1Name | highlight:vm.search"></span>
```

When I search using special character like [ or (, I get angular exception and application breaks.

> SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(/: Unterminated group
>       at new RegExp (native)
>       at v. (http://localhost:50463/EIA/source/dist/vendor.min.js:72:1157)
>       at i (http://localhost:50463/EIA/source/dist/vendor.min.js:38:92754)
>       at cr.| (http://localhost:50463/EIA/source/dist/vendor.min.js:38:86832)
>       at h.constant (http://localhost:50463/EIA/source/dist/vendor.min.js:38:92126)
>       at Object.e (http://localhost:50463/EIA/source/dist/vendor.min.js:38:101832)
>       at v.$digest (http://localhost:50463/EIA/source/dist/vendor.min.js:38:57280)
>       at v.$apply (http://localhost:50463/EIA/source/dist/vendor.min.js:38:58986)
>       at http://localhost:50463/EIA/source/dist/client.js:1007:31
>       at http://localhost:50463/EIA/source/dist/vendor.min.js:38:64888 undefined

I tried using ng-sanitize library but still I get the same error.

Please, how could I resolve that?

Comment: This code cause applciation to break
text.replace(new RegExp(search, 'gi'), '<span class="ui-match">$&</span>');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should [escape your RegExp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3446170/1064325) input since `(` is a special character for regular expressions:

```
function escapeRegExp(str) {
  return str.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");
}
```

Then, just use it:

```
new RegExp(escapeRegExp(search), 'gi')
```